# "How many coins here" vs. "How many coins are here"?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

What is the correct form of the following sentence? Do I need to add auxiliary verbs?

> How many coins **are** here?

or

> How many coins here?

Comment: I don't see how "are" is an "auxiliary verb" here.  Without "are", there isn't *any* verb in the sentence, and English sentences need verbs.

Comment: What you need is there: How many coins are there here?

Answer (score 2):

The correct sentence is:

> How many coins are here?

The second sentence is not correct and I would really only expect to hear it from a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences mean the same and are correct

> **How many coins here?
>
>   How many coins are here?**

If anything, the first sounds more **informal**, almost as if the person standing next to a table was pointing to the coins on it.

The second sounds more **formal** like two people are looking at coins on a table, and one asks as if it was a test.